# Retry and Circuit Breaker Patterns using Polly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core-2.2, polly

Could someone please explain to me how Polly supports to implement Retry and Circuit Breaker patterns? As per their documentation there offer multiple resilience policies, Retry and Circuit-breaker are two of them.

Let's say I have a scenario with a service that does an HTTP call to a certain endpoint, This endpoint could return HTTP 429, 504 etc. In such a scenario, I want to retry the request a few times, let's say 2 times before sending a response to the caller.

So, Which Polly resilience policy could I use for this scenario? Retry or Circuit-breaker? Can I use them both? If so how?

What is the difference between them?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-retry-pattern-in-asp-net-core-via-polly/

Comment: http://blog.rogatnev.net/2016/07/patterns-retry-vs-circuit-breaker.html

Comment: https://medium.com/@trongdan_tran/circuit-breaker-and-retry-64830e71d0f6

Comment: Check out the Polly Samples to see combinations of retry and circuit-breaker in action: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly-Samples . Check out also the Polly wiki https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki doco, which shows detailed flows for both retry and circuit-breaker, and PolicyWrap (with flow diagrams) for combining them: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap

Comment: @mountaintraveller Thank you for pointing towards the documentation and examples, really appreciate it.